# How to find the sum of a column generated from a query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So, I'm im doing a ticket style database and i'm trying to find the sum of the tickets generated from this. I have attached my query below and the result of it

[QUERY RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJHn0.png)

```
SELECT Price, TicketID, Ticket.TicketType
FROM Price, Ticket
WHERE Price.TicketType = Ticket.TicketType
;
```

In the picture, I am trying to get a total for all of the prices that you see in there, each ticketID is a new ticket sold. I can click the totals button in access and it puts a total below it, but I need the total done in the query, so I am wondering how I could do this.

Comment: Have you looked into using `group by` and `sum`?

Comment: What are your expected results?  Perhaps you could use `union all` to return the summed results as the final row?

Comment: Sum of all price values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, learn to use proper `join` syntax.  Commmas in the `FROM` clause are simply an archaic way to represent a `join`.

From what you say, you want `sum()`:

```
SELECT SUM(Price)
FROM Price JOIN
     Ticket
     ON Price.TicketType = Ticket.TicketType;
```

This may or may not do exactly what you want.  It answers the question quite specifically.

Comment: EDIT: This works aslong as i use INNER JOIN. For some reason my teacher however stated that she didn't want the SQL code looking like we did it in design view, I know i saw inner joins in design view alot so I never wrote it that away. I go to a community college and my teacher teaches DB from a quite old style, I believe. thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Use the SUM function:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

I think this can help

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the sum function as I am using my cheatsheat our teacher made us, this made it clearer. Using the INNER JOIN command this was easy to do, but it does look like i made the code in design view which the teacher doesn't like, but, hey it works lol

Comment: this is a link only answer -- please post an actual answer or make this a comment.